# how to create a plot with continuous days of year of subsequent years as x axis in R?

Tags: r, days

I am trying to plot temperature data of two consecutive years (say 05 Nov, 2010 to 30 March, 2011) having days of year as x axis values. For example:

```
temp<-c(30.1:40.1) # y axis
doy<-c(360:365,1:5) # x axis
```

please help me out. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
temp<-c(30.1:40.1) # y axis
doy<-c(360:365,1:5) # x axis

doy2 <- c(360:365,c(1:5)+365)

plot(temp ~ doy2, xaxt="n", xlab = "doy")
axis(1,doy,at=doy2)
```

Alternatively:

The most rigorous way of approaching this would be to use the date-time objects within R. Then R will recognise the 'temp' data as dates, and will therefore give the right result when plotted. Date time objects are complicated, but if you deal with them regularly, they are worth learning:

```
temp<-c(30.1:40.1) # y axis
doy<-c(360:365,1:5) # x axis

doy2 <- c(360:365,c(1:5)+365)  #we sill need this to place numbers 1:5 into a new year (i.e. 365 days later)


doy.date <- as.Date("2011-01-01")   #Set a base date (choose the year that you will start with

doy.date <- doy.date + doy2 - 1  #add the days of year to the base date and subtract one (the base date was January 1st)

plot(temp ~ doy.date, xlab = "doy")    #plot as usual

#see documentation on dates
?date

#or for date with times:
?POSIXct
```

Comment: @user1968046 Did this solve your question? If so please mark as answer. Otherwise please explain why not, then I will try to help further.

Comment: thank you Tom Evans. your suggestion have solved my problem. i would love to know the other approaches also for this issue with explanation. thanks. please reply if you got time.

Comment: I added a second suggestion to the answer above. It uses date-time objects, which are very powerful, but a little complicated. They are definitely worth learning though if you deal with date and time data frequently.